# Расшифровка тернарного оператора

Tags: javascript

Как записывается эта формула полностью?

```
e += (i == 10) ? i : i + ', ';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (i == 10)
  e = e + i
else
  e = e + (i +', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let _i;
if (i == 10) 
  _i = i
else 
  _i = i + ', ';
e = e + _i;
```